# In mercurial how do I get the difference between two version numbers of a repo?

Tags: mercurial

I want hg to output a diff for each file that was changed between two different version numbers.

Is this possible?

Comment: no versions in hg, revisions or changesets. Changeset define the state of **all files in repo** for /somemoment/. Re-think your question and mercurial terminology

Comment: He may have tagged his changesets with version numbers. If that's not the case, though, you are right; the terminology is important to get straight!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `hg help diff`

```
hg diff [OPTION]... ([-c REV] | [-r REV1 [-r REV2]]) [FILE]...
```

Try `hg diff -r<x> -r<y>` - where `<x>` and `<y>` are your revision numbers.

Comment: Just a note for shorter syntax `hg diff -r rev1:rev2`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a GUI such as TortoiseHg (my personal preference) and trying to figure out what has been changed between the two versions, you can update to the older changeset and merge the newer one to it. The directory state will then be the sum of all the changes made between the two. You could also use this technique along with some scripting to get actual diffs if that's what you really need.

Whichever you do, you don't want to commit the fake merge. Use update --clean (or your GUI's equivalent - in THG it's a checkbox in the Update dialog) to discard the local changes from the merge.